# QQmlComponent initialization

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qqmlcomponent

i have an application which sets properties of Qml from C++, so far i was able to set property of any type. I am able to create QQmlComponent in C++ and set it to property.

But first i need to initialize component with its properties. I can do that with create/beginCreate and set properties. But i cant change created QObject back to QQmlComponent, therefor i cant set it to givent Component type property.

Is there some way how to conver QObject to QQmlComponent ? Or is there any other way to initialize QQmlComponent properties ?

Example, of what i want to achiev in C++, how it looks in qml

```
import QtQuick 2.3

Loader {
    // property of type Component
    sourceComponent: Text {
    
        text: "property i want to intialize, this component can be in file"
    }
}
```

**Edit:** I will clarify what im after. Suppose i have something like JSON given by user.
e.g:

```
{
   "type":"Loader",
   "sourceComponent":{
      "type":"Text",
      "text":"some property of property of type QQmlComponentProperty"
   }
}
```

Then from C++ i create given items, problem is how to create QQmlComponent with user given properties.

Comment: I think you don't understand it quite right. A component is kind of template you create an item from. item - it is an instance, component is a template. you cannot convert on to another and back. I guess you have to clarify your question. What exactly do you want to archive?

Comment: i have file defined by user, which has properties of some qml object (e.g Rectangle etc). in this file can be properties of type QQmlComponent and i dont know how to assign their properties. I will give example in question.

Comment: Added another example hope its is clearer now :)

Comment: Ok, when you create an object, I guess using [QQmlComponent::create](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlcomponent.html#create) you get a pointer to  QObject, and so you can set/get a property you want using the [Qt property system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html#reading-and-writing-properties-with-the-meta-object-system), for example `ptr->setProperty("text","some property of property of type QQmlComponentProperty")`. I mean you set a property to _instance_, not to _component_.

Comment: yes thats what im doing, but you cannot then set sourceComponent with created instance because its different type. Thats what im after :)

Comment: do you mean Loader? what a sense to use Loader for already created component? Loader _instantiates_ item from component. If you already have an instance there is no need to use Loader.

Comment: loader is just example. Other example would be CircularGauge, which has style Property.

Comment: It doesn't matter, the principle is the same. You set property to an instance, not to a Component. Component has no properties except its own. It doesn't even exist. You can change an instance of item, not the template / type. The example in C++ - `int i = 10` ... you cannot change the type - `int`, but you can change the instance - `i`. a class would be more appropriate as an example but it's the same ...

Comment: yeah i know that i cant cant change type but intsnace of component after create() is QObject, i cant set QObject to QQmlComponent. Or maybe i dont understand you :)

Comment: why you want to set QObject to QQmlComponent?

Comment: Because its what i get after i create an instance of QQmlComponent (becuase i dont have way to assign its initial properties) with QQmlComponent.create()

Comment: I really don't understand. You have the pointer of type `QObject *` to the instance of your component. Now you can set/change any property you want. Why do you want to assign it to `QQmlComponent`? Looks like XY problem ...

Comment: because created instance should be a property value (but instance is QObject and type of property im assingnig it to is QQmlComponent see example).

Comment: property of what? please provide example

Comment: Rather than describing your C++ code, please show what you have tried.